# Parsley.js 2.0.2 require not working, but other validation works

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, validation, parsley.js

Since this has already wasted a day and a half of my life, I am bringing it to the community someone can save me while I still have some hair left to pull out.

I am attempting to use parsley.js and it actually works for the most part, except when I simply want to do something as basic as requiring that a field has ANY value.

I know that Parsley.js is loading, and I know its working, because for example, if its looking for an email address, and I add one character to the field and submit it, the form stops the submit and correctly outputs an error message indicating I must have an email in the field. As I type an email, the validation works and turns green as soon as a valid email is recognized. So it works just fine for that part. The problem is that despite me indicating that the field is required, parsley seems to let the form submit if there is no value in the field. I would like it to throw an error if the field is blank, thats the part thats not working. But even putting one character in the field causes the rest of the validation to work, but a blank field slides right through. Please let me know any ideas you all have.

```
<form role="form" action="" method="POST" class="parsley-validate">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Email:</label>
    <input type="text" data-parsley-require="true" data-parsley-type="email" class="form-control">
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Seems basic enough right? I can not possibly figure out why the require is not working. Maybe someone with more parsley experience can help me out with a trick that I am not seeing.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="parsley.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $('.parsley-validate').parsley();
</script>
```

Obviously I call parsley on the form as well & load jquery, like I said, if i add a character in the field it will validate. But for some reason if the field is empty it goes through.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo - the attribute should be "data-parsley-required" not "data-parsley-require". You can find working example here http://jsfiddle.net/2p7Pz/

```
<form role="form" action="" method="POST" class="parsley-validate">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Email:</label>
      <input type="text" data-parsley-required="true" data-parsley-type="email" class="form-control" />
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: You got it! Needed that clean pair of eyes.